# Extracting values after pattern

Tags: r

A beginner question...

I have a list like this:

```
x <- c("aa=v12, bb=x21, cc=f35", "xx=r53, bb=g-25, yy=h48", "nn=u75, bb=26, gg=m98")
```

(but many more lines)

I need to extract what is between "bb=" and ",". I.e. I want:

```
x21  
g-25  
26
```

Having read many similar questions here, I suppose it is stringr with str_extract I should use, but somehow I can't get it to work. Thanks for all help.

/Chris

Comment: I'd avoid using `t` as an object name since `t()` is used for transposing matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strapply` in the gsubfn package can do that. Note that `[^,]*` matches a string of non-commas.

`strapply` extracts the back referenced portion (the part within parentheses):

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(x, "bb=([^,]*)", simplify = TRUE)
[1] "x21"  "g-25" "26"
```

If there are several `x` vectors then provide them in a list like this:

```
> strapply(list(x, x), "bb=([^,]*)")
[[1]]
[1] "x21"  "g-25" "26"  

[[2]]
[1] "x21"  "g-25" "26"
```

Answer (score 2):

An option using `regexpr`:

```
> temp = regexpr('bb=[^,]*', x)
> substr(x, temp + 3, temp + attr(temp, 'match.length') - 1)
[1] "x21"  "g-25" "26"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using the base regex functions in R. First we use `strsplit` to split on the comma. Then we use `grepl` to filter only the items that start with `bb=` and `gsub` to extract all the characters after `bb=`.

```
> x <- c("aa=v12, bb=x21, cc=f35", "xx=r53, bb=g-25, yy=h48", "nn=u75, bb=26, gg=m98")
> y <- unlist(strsplit(x , ","))
> unlist(lapply(y[grepl("bb=", y)], function(x) gsub("^.*bb=(.*)", "\\1", x)))
[1] "x21"  "g-25" "26"
```

It looks like `str_replace` is the function you are after if you want to go that route:

```
> str_replace(y[grepl("bb=",y)], "^.*bb=(.*)", "\\1")
[1] "x21"  "g-25" "26"
```

Answer (score 1):

Read it in with commas as separators and take the second column:

```
> x.split <- read.table(textConnection(x), header=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[2]] 
[1] " bb=x21"  " bb=g-25" " bb=26"
```

Then remove the "bb="

```
> gsub("bb=", "", x.split ) 
[1] " x21"  " g-25" " 26"
```